# What is the function that is not an $L^p$ function on sphere?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to show that
$ \int_{\partial B} |f|^p ds = \infty$ where B is unit ball. What is the f function?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = \frac{1}{|x-u|^d}$ in dimension $d$ and for any unitary vector $u$ works.